# Is IAP mandatory?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, subscription

I am working on an iOS app which provides access to below features when user purchases the annual subscription:

- **Book Doctor Visit:** After purchasing the subscription,the user can have the access to the feature of booking an appointment with doctor so he/she can visit the clinic for assessment.
- **Chat with Doctor:** After purchasing the subscription, user can chat with the doctor for any consultation using chat functionality from the app.

**My question is**, do I have to compulsory implement IAP for this or I can use any other payment method like RazorPay, Stripe ?

I have gone through apple's guidelines regarding the IAP, but I am confused after reading it.
You can find the guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#business).

**EDIT:** After some suggestions, edited the first feature description for more clarity.

Comment: The first service you mentioned "Book Doctor Visit" is something that enables the user to access the feature in the app to book an appointment or it's the doctor booking fee ?

Comment: @NajeeburRehman That gives access to user to book an appointment from the app.

Comment: That means it is the access to the feature in the app not the payment for the outside product or service. Then it should be implemented as In-App purchases.

Comment: But as per apple documentation section 3.1.5(a) Goods and Services Outside of the App , we can't use IAP for services which are going to be used outside of the app. The service is "Visiting the clinic", booking appointment is the way to use that service.

Comment: But in your case you are not charging appointment fee ? As you said earlier it will allow user to access the feature of booking an appointment. Its the feature in the app that you are selling.

Comment: To be simple and clear if you are selling any app feature then you have to use IAP.

Comment: This was the reason for my confusion.I am still confused about this point, as you can read few answers below, they are contradictory to your opinion.

Comment: I think this is due to the unclarity in your question. You should be asked liked “Allow the user to access the feature of booking an appointment”

Comment: @NajeeburRehman Just edited the first feature description. Hope that is clear enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following on from Pauls answer which is indeed correct. I'll validate that with direct quotes.

Relating to your first & second use case; [3.1.1 In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments)

> If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by
>   way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access
>   to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app
>   purchase. Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or
>   functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR
>   codes, etc....

Within feature 1, the first 4 words answer your question. Purchasing the subscription, and/or booking an appointment through the app consists an unlockable functionality through that subscription and is therefore mandated to be an IAP.

Feature 2 allows the user to chat with the doctor for any consultation using the chat functionality within the app; this is both defined as an unlock within the app & premium content therefore in-app purchases are compulsory under this feature.

Hope this gains some clarity

Edit; The first feature was somewhat poorly worded however upon clarification both uses cases are subject to [3.1.1 In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments).

Comment: Thanks Harry, I have edited the first feature description after @Najeeb's suggestion. Can you please make sure your answer is still valid for the same?

Comment: @VishalSonawane I have updated my answer to be more aligned with your updated question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You **must** use in-app purchase for your use cases as the services are delivered **in the app**. An external payments system can't be used.

Comment: Thanks!. Still just to be more sure, have you done this before? I don't want to assume the things. Can you share any documentation or a proper guide for this.

Comment: The information is in the guidelines that you linked to.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting the document in simple and straight forward way. Apple has ruined the simplicity of documentation.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I have edited the first feature description after @Najeeb's suggestion. Can you please make sure your answer is still valid for the same?

Comment: If the payment is for the ability to book an appointment and the appointment is made in the app then IAP must be used.